# starting after upgrade to 14.01

Tags: 14.04

I upgraded to 14.01, and it will not start. I get to the screen with UBUNTU and five dots
alternatively lit, but nothing more happens. The arrows produc a blsk screen with lots 
of `starting..` the last one being `Starting CUPS printing spooler/server`, then nothing more.

Choosing recovery mode, then he root start option I try writing `startx`
It again produces lots of lines, terminating with

```
 fatal server error.
 Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tXO-lock
```

Please tell me what I can do, or what informations I can send to receive help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the dots, do you still see a GRUB screen showing previous kernels, previous versions?  If you aren't using a dual boot, you might never have paid attention to it, but now is when it can help you.  The first item below the default is recovery mode, which itself might help you, or trying a previous version.  I've had to do this a few times to correct my last mistake.

After you get your computer to boot, I'd advise you to open the Update Manager, and click CHECK before running the updates.  I suspect that after some updates your installation will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like interrupted upgrade.

startx wouldn't help in this case.

In root rescue shell try:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get install -f
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then:

```
exit
```

By the way, in rescue mode is possible to select "dpkg" to fix broken packages:

http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/ubuntu-not-booting-try-repairing-broken-packages-in-recovery-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I tried to upgrade to the 14.04LTS Trusty Tahr. The easiest way would be to get an installation cd for the 14.01 version and run it. Remove all the previous versions and install the 14.01 ,and after booting install all the available updates in update manager...and you should preferably create a backup of all the data in an external harddisk before starting the installation so that no data is lost.